# How to create an instance of the deployed contract in Truffle Console?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

I am trying to learn Truffle tool using the tutorial at:
[Truffle tutorial](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/reentrancy-attack-on-a-smart-contract-677eae1300f2)

I am writing the following command at Truffle console to create an instance of the deployed contract but I am getting the message "undefined":

`Victim.deployed().then(contract => victim = contract)`

> undefined

```
truffle(ganache)> truffle version
```

> Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27)
>
> Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
>
> Node v8.10.0
>
> Web3.js v1.2.1
>
> truffle(ganache)>

Somebody please guide me how to create an instance of contract in Truffle Console?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you wrote?

Comment: Please open my question, I have corrected it.

Comment: The Truffle-Console utility simply prints the value returned from the call. Since `Victim.deployed().then(...)` doesn't return anything, this utility prints `undefined`. It doesn't mean that the code in the callback function that you have passed to it (`contract => victim = contract`) has not been executed.

Comment: What is meant by the "then" part i.e. "(contract => victim = contract)", what is this operator "=>" and how the then part got associated with "Victim.deployed()"

Comment: This is a Javascript question, so you should search it online (i.e., google it, and then click the first link to Stack Overflow). What to google? I guess, "what is => in javascript". In short, `contract => victim = contract` is equivalent to `function (contract) {return victim = contract;}`, which is essentially a function which takes one argument (`contract`). I guess you could also google "passing a function to another function in javascript". This question is not about Ethereum.

Comment: I am getting garbage output, why?:     truffle(ganache)> Victim.deployed().then(contract => victim = contract)
TruffleContract {
  constructor: 
   { [Function: TruffleContract]
     _constructorMethods: 
      { configureNetwork: [Function: configureNetwork],
        setProvider: [Function: setProvider],
        new: [Function: new],
        at: [AsyncFunction: at],
        deployed: [AsyncFunction: deployed],
        defaults: [Function: defaults],